# bash 2> >(command) > >(command) not getting it

Tags: bash

Been following this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16283739/15603477) great answer.
The following part I don't understand.

```
$ ls -ld /tmp /tnt 2> >(sed 's/^/E: /') > >(sed 's/^/O: /')
O: drwxrwxrwt 17 root root 28672 Nov  5 23:00 /tmp
E: ls: cannot access /tnt: No such file or directory
```

and this also.

```
$ ((ls -ld /tmp /tnt |sed 's/^/O: /' >&9 ) 2>&1 |sed 's/^/E: /') 9>&1| cat -n
     1  O: drwxrwxrwt 118 root root 196608 Jan  7 12:29 /tmp
     2  E: ls: cannot access /tnt: No such file or directory
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Introduction
`E:`  and `O:`  part still not getting it.

---

**The following is my interpretation**

```
$ ls -ld /tmp /tnt 2> >(sed 's/^/E: /') > >(sed 's/^/O: /')
```

2 refers to stderr, the command `ls -ld /tmp /tnt` 's error will be evaluated in `(sed 's/^/E: /')`, `^` refer to the beginning of the line, the beginning will be replaced with **E:**
`>(sed 's/^/O: /')` == `1>(sed 's/^/O: /')`
1 refers to stdout, the normal output will be evaluated in `(sed 's/^/O: /')` The beginning will be replaced by **O:**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>(...)` is called [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html). It lets the "outer" program write to the "inner" program as if it were a file.

See also page on [redirectors in bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html).

`E:` and `O:` are what the author of the comment used to indicate Error (`stderr`) and Standard Output (`stdout`) output form the commands with the command piped through `sed`.

`sed 's/^/E: /'` looks for the beginning of line (`^`)
and replaces it (adds) with `E:` or `O:` as in the second part of the command.

Comment: Can you further explain it. It's just little bit hard for me.  another part is sed.
`E:` and `O: ` I don't get  it, even manual is here: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Introduction

Comment: E: and O: are what the author of the comment used to indicate Error (stderr) and Standard Output (stdout) output form the commands with the command piped through sed.

Comment: I added my interpretation, is it correct?

Comment: yes, that sounds alright